# Remove / cancel animations in ui router when navigating back and forth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS ui router and I have about 3 pages in total. The problem I am facing is that on the home page (first page) I have an intro animation which lasts about 10 seconds in total. The intro animation is attached to the directive.

Now once I land on that page, the intro starts and everything is fine until I navigate to another page - it seems that the intro keeps playing as if the DOM and in particular - the directive was not removed properly.

Is there a way to remove / clear DOM before navigating to another page?

The code is massive to post here and I was wondering if there is a quick fix for this? If not, I will try to post it on jsfiddle.

Comment: How you animate your intro?

Comment: I use TweenMax for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabe something like this will help

```
.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location) {
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) { {
      //to.name is new state name
      //from.name is old state name
       TweenMax.killTweensOf($("#yourId"));  

    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! that did the trick, thank you! It's strange why TweenMax keeps going in the background, as the DOM is actually being removed (looking at it from firebug). Thanks again.